# ¿Por que me marca que aún no he declarado expression en el return de variableVarion? Uso PEG.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

El código es para un lenguaje que estoy creando. Está escrito en PEG.js y al compilar me marca error de referencia.

El error "ReferenceError: expression is not defined" indica que estás intentando usar la variable expression en un lugar donde no está definida o no ha sido declarada previamente en el código.

Ya intente cambiarlo de lugar pero sigue siendo el mismo problema.

Sigo creyendo que es un error de posición pero no estoy seguro ya que también se puede deber a un error en la sintaxis y debido a ese error me marca error en otra línea y estoy escribiendo de más sólo para que pueda publicar.

```js
start 
= variableLoc / variableVarion / variableConst / variableEntro / variableDal / variableTex / declaracionFunciones / llamarFuncion / login /ingre / ingreNum /ingretro / ingreDal

  //funciones
  declaracionFunciones =
  "func" space id:id "(" parameterList:parameterList? ")" "{" statement:statement* "}" {
    return { type: "declaracionFunciones", id, parameterList:parameterList || [], statement };
  }

  llamarFuncion =
  id:id "(" parameterList:parameterList? ")" ";" {
    return { type: "llamarFuncion", id, parameterList: parameterList || [] };
  }

   login
  = "login" space "(" target:id "," value:expression "," optionalTarget:id? ")" ";" {
    return { type: "login", target, value, optionalTarget: optionalTarget || null };
  }

  ingre = "ingre" space? "(" target:id ")" ";" {
  variable[target] = prompt(target);
  return { type: "ingre", target, value: variable[target] };
  }

  ingreNum = "ingreNum" space? "(" target:id ")" ";" {
  
  Number.isFloat = Number.isFloat || function(value) {
  return typeof value === 'number' && 
    isFinite(value) &&
    Math.floor(value) !== value;
};
  let inputValue = prompt(target);
  let num = prompt(target);
  let parsedValue = Number(inputValue);
  
  if (Number.isInteger(parsedValue)) {
    variable[target] = parseInt(num);
  } else if (Number.isFloat(parsedValue)) {
    variable[target] = parseFloat(num);
  } else {
    try {
      throw new Error("Sintax error");
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error.message);
    }
  }
  
  return { type: "ingreNum", target, value: variable[target] };
};

  ingretro = "ingretro" space? "("target:id")" ";" {
    variable[target] = parseInt(prompt(target));
    return { type: "ingretro", target, value: variable[target] };
  };

  ingreDal = "ingreDal" space? "("target:id")" ";" {
    
  Number.isFloat = Number.isFloat || function(value) {
  return typeof value === 'number' && 
    isFinite(value) &&
    Math.floor(value) !== value;
};
    variable[target] = parseFloat(prompt(target));
    return { type: "ingretro", target, value: variable[target] };
  };

  //Declaración de variables
  variableLoc =
  "loc" space id:id (space? "=" space? expression:expression)? ";" {
    return { type: "variableLoc", id, expression:expression, isLocal: true };
  }

  variableVarion =
  "varion" space id:id (space? "=" space? expression: expression)? ";" {
    return { type: "variableVarion", id, expression: expr, isGlobal: true };
  }

  variableConst = 
  "const" space id:id (space? "=" space? expression)? ";" {
    return { type: "variableConst", id, expression, isConstant: true, isLocal: true };
  }

  variableTex =
  "tex" space id:id (space? "=" space? string:string)? ";" {
    return { type: "variableTex", id, string:string, isLocal: true};
  }

  variableEntro =
  "entro" space id:id (space? "=" space? numberEntro:numberEntro)? ";" {
    return { type: "variableEntro", id, numberEntro:numberEntro, isLocal: true };
  }

  variableDal =
  "dal" space id:id (space? "=" space? numberDal:numberDal)? ";" {
    return { type:"variableDal", id, numberDal:numberDal, isLocal: true };
  }

  //Reglas de declaración de variable
  id = [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* {
  return text();
  }

  expression = number / string / boolean / id

  //Numeros
  number = integer / float / negativeInteger / negativeFloat / specialValue

  numberEntro = integer / negativeInteger

  numberDal = float / negativeFloat

  integer = [0-9]+ {
  return parseInt(text(), 10);
  }

  float = [0-9]+ "." [0-9]+ {
  return parseFloat(text(), 10);
  }

  negativeInteger = "-" integer {
  return -parseInt(text(), 10);
  }

  negativeFloat = "-" float {
  return -parseFloat(text(), 10);
  }

  specialValue = "NaN" {
    return { type: "specialValue", value: NaN };
  }
  / "INF" {
    return { type: "specialValue", value: Infinity };
  }
  / "-INF" {
    return { type: "specialValue", value: -Infinity };
  }

  //Strings
  string = stringDouble / stringSingle / stringTemplate / stringTemplateContent

  stringDouble = '"' chars:stringContent* '"' {
  return chars.join('');
  }

  stringSingle = "'" chars:(stringContent / "\\'")* "'" {
  return chars.join('');
  }

  stringTemplate = "`" chars:stringTemplateContent* "`" {
  return chars.join('');
  }

  stringTemplateContent = "${" expression:expression "}" {
    return "${" + expression + "}";
  }
  / [^$]+


  stringContent = [^\"] / "\\" . ;

  //Booleanos
  boolean = "true" / "false" {
    return text() === "true";
  }

  //Reglas de funciones
  parameterList
  = parameter (space "," space parameter)*

  parameter
  = expression:expression space id:id {
    return { type: "parameter", expression:expression, name: id };
  }

  outputStatement
  = "consola" ":" expression:expression ";" {
    return { type: "outputStatement", target: "consola", value: expression };
  }
  / "documento" ":" expression:expression ";" {
    return { type: "outputStatement", target: "documento", value: expression };
  }

  statement
  = outputStatement/ login / expression / assignment / returnStatement

  assignment
  = id:id space "=" space expression:expression ";" {
  return { type: "assignment", variable: id, value: expression };
  }

  returnStatement
  = "regresa" space expression:expression ";" {
  return { type: "returnStatement", value: expression };
  }

  //Reglas generales
  space = " "*

  variable = statement:statement {
  return { variables: {}, statement };
  }
```